I am trying to define the next highest BSL
I have BSL defined as a 3 candle pattern where the middle candles high is highest of the 3. So the left high and right high are both lower than the middle high. I also want it to be so that the BSL is higher than the candle before the current ones high. I also want it to be so that this high is plotted as a line from where the high was created. This is my code so far:
//@version=5
indicator("Buyside Liquidity", overlay=true)

// Function to check if a candle is a buyside liquidity
isBuysideLiquidity(index) =>
    high[index + 1] > high[index] and high[index + 1] > high[index + 2] and high[index + 1] < high[1]

// Find the index of the buy-side liquidity point
var int buysideIndex = na
buysideIndex := ta.barssince(isBuysideLiquidity(1)) + 2

// Plot buyside liquidity
plot(high[buysideIndex])

This seems to plot the high of every candle which I am very confused about. I have also tried other things but a lot of the time it doesnt include the last part about how that high needs to be higher than the the candle before the current ones high. This is that code as well:
//@version=5
indicator("Buyside Liquidity", overlay=true)

// Function to check if a candle is a buyside liquidity
isBuysideLiquidity(index) =>
    high[index + 1] > high[index] and high[index + 1] > high[index + 2]                

// Find the index of the buy-side liquidity point
var int buysideIndex = na
buysideIndex := ta.barssince(isBuysideLiquidity(1)) + 2

// Plot buyside liquidity
//plotshape(high[buysideIndex], style=shape.triangleup, location=location.abovebar, color=color.green, size=size.small)

plot(high[buysideIndex])

